# Symfony Console Ask helper not working if called from composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

In my application I'm using the [Symfony/Console](https://github.com/symfony/console) package (v. 3.2.7) and I created several commands that works fine.

Now I'm trying to automate some tasks and I added in the composer.json scripts sections

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": [
            "@php app/console myproject:setup"
        ]
    }
```

And the code in the command is

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;

/**
 * Class SetupCommand
 * @package WpSkeletonCLI\Command
 */
class SetupCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myproject:setup');
        $this->setDescription('A setup wizard for your brand new skeleton based project.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->getHelper('question')->ask($input, $output, new ConfirmationQuestion('Are you displaying this question?', false));
    }
}
```

If I run the command from console, it works fine, but if I run the command in the same way from composer it doesn't work, it displays no errors and the question is not showed. I tried to add print command just to know if the command is call properly and I can see all my print examples (both methods).

I red also the [scripts section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) on Composer, the only thing I noticed is that I'm not using the Composer Event object.

Maybe the Symfony Question Helper is not compatible with running script from Composer?

Comment: seems an [open issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3299)

Comment: I think you're right. Thank you

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @LeeviGraham no, the issue is still open and I didn't find a workaround

Comment: @stuzzo I found a couple of open tickets in composer / symonfy project. Looks like it's a known issue but doesn't have much traction.